# Strategy to guessing dynamic number

Tags: probability, combinatorics, game-theory

I pick an arbitrary number between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$. In addition, I pick another "jump" number. 
At each turn, a person needs to guess what my current number is.
The only answer for each guess will either be true or false (no more hints are given).
For every wrong guess, I update my current number by adding the jump number.

Can you please suggest a winning strategy for this game?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! It's common courtesy to explain a bit what you yourself have tried to solve this problem, and maybe give some context on why you need it (e.g. homework). Also, are you picking integers or real numbers?

Comment: There is no such thing as picking a random number (with equal probabilities) between $-\infty$ and $\infty$, at least in the standard interpretation of the theory of probability. Probabilities of disjoint events are $\sigma$-additive, which means they add up in the finite and in the *countably infinite* case. Thus, if the probability of picking any number is $>0$, they add up to infinity, if the probability of picking any number is $0$, they all add up to $0$ - but they must all add up to $1$, which is a contradiction. Thus, you need to specify a *distribution* of the "random" choice.

Comment: It is like a discrete uniform distribution between (−∞ ,∞),
this puzzle was asked during an interview.

Comment: Does the person who is guessing know the value of "Jump"?

Comment: the person who is guessing does not know the value of jump

Comment: @user6041789 There is no such thing as the discrete uniform distribution between $(-\infty, \infty)$ as I said. The interview question does not make sense. In addition, even if we could make *some* sense of it, I would never play such a game, knowing a priori that the probability of your number being at most the size of Graham's number (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number) is still zero!

Comment: ok, for simplicity,  lets say it is a discrete uniform distribution between (-1000,1000),
after solving for this case, i will try to expand it to more general case.

Comment: @StinkingBishop The question makes sense if you replace “random” with “arbitrary.” This is a classic puzzle.

Comment: I’m guessing that by number, you mean integer. Otherwise, if the sequence is made out of real numbers, there’s no winning strategy. Every guess will be correct only for a family of starting numbers $s$ and jump numbers $j$, lying on a line. So countably many guesses will correspond to countably many lines, that can’t cover the plane. Therefore, no matter how we guess, there will exist $s$, $j$ for which we’ll fail every time.

Answer (score 2):

First, we create a surjection $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}^2$. An explicit example can be given by “spiraling” around an infinite square grid.

Now, at turn $n$ (indexed at zero), we calculate $f(n)=(s,j)$, and guess the number $s+jn$. We’ll guess correctly if the starting number was $s$ and the jump number was $j$, or if we simply got lucky.

Since we’ll try every single starting number and jump number, we’re guaranteed to eventually guess correctly.

Comment: Ah, finally I understand the question, given this solution. Just can you please replace the word "injection" with "surjection".